# How to show in controller lifetime in Symfony 1 and 2

Tags: php, symfony1, symfony, symfony-1.4

How to show in controller the **remaining** time to expire the session in Symfony 1 and 2?

Answer (score 0):

This can now be done in Symfony 2.1. According to the session config [doc](http://symfony.com/doc/master/components/http_foundation/session_configuration.html#session-meta-data), you can use the new [`MetadataBag`](http://api.symfony.com/master/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/Session/Storage/MetadataBag.html).

`$session->getMetadataBag()->getCreated();` will give you when the session was created and `$session->getMetadataBag()->getLifetime();` will give you the lifetime of the cookie. Simply subtract from the current time and you should get the remaining time until expiration.